# WPF Button no 'Click' attribute

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.5

I'm real new to WPF. I'm using .NET 4.5.

For some reason, my button has no `Click` attribute in intellisense. When I type it in anyway like below, I get an 'Invalid Markup' error in Blend.

Why is there is no `Click` attribute here?

Do I have to use commands?

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.UI.Windows.windowLoadFiles"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Load Files" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="menuMain" IsMainMenu="True" Height="Auto">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem x:Name="menuItem_Main_File_Exit" Header="E_xit" Click="menuItem_Main_File_Exit_Click"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <GroupBox Margin="5,0,5,5" Header="Source *" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBox x:Name="textSourceDirectory"></TextBox>
                <Button x:Name="buttonSelectSourceDirectory" Content="Browse..." Click="buttonSelectSourceDirectory_Click"></Button>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AjS suggested above, building the solution in Visual Studio shed accurate light on the issue.

`GroupBox` can only have one child element. This means that if you want more than one, you need to add them to a `Panel` of some type.

The following has fixed my issue:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.UI.Windows.windowLoadFiles"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Load Files" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="menuMain" IsMainMenu="True" Height="Auto">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem x:Name="menuItem_Main_File_Exit" Header="E_xit" Click="menuItem_Main_File_Exit_Click"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <GroupBox Margin="5,0,5,5" Header="Source *" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textSourceDirectory"></TextBox>
                    <Button x:Name="buttonSelectSourceDirectory" Content="Browse..." Click="buttonSelectSourceDirectory_Click"></Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I need to wait a couple of days. I'll also wait to see if a more comprehensive answer is posted.